# Vala: warning and segmentation fault with to_utf32_fast method

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, vala

I got a warning and a segmentation fault when compiling and running roughly the following code, which uses the `to_utf32_fast` method on a `string` and should return the number of UTF-32 characters encoded in the `codepoint_count` variable. This method transpiles to the C function `g_utf8_to_ucs4_fast` and somehow `out codepoint_count` ends up as `long * *` argument instead of the expected `long *`.

I do have a workaround, so this isn't urgent.

```
int main (string[] args) {
    string test = "abc";
    long codepoint_count;
    string utf32_version = test.to_utf32_fast(-1, out codepoint_count).to_string();
    stdout.printf("success");
    return 0;
}
```

The relevant part of the output:

```
C:/msys64/usr/src/outerror.vala.c: In function '_vala_main':
C:/msys64/usr/src/outerror.vala.c:78:50: warning: passing argument 3 of 'g_utf8_to_ucs4_fast' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  _tmp2_ = g_utf8_to_ucs4_fast (test, (glong) -1, &_tmp1_);
                                                  ^
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstring.h:33:0,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib/giochannel.h:34,
                 from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:54,
                 from C:/msys64/usr/src/outerror.vala.c:5:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/glib-2.0/glib/gunicode.h:798:12: note: expected 'glong * {aka long int *}' but argument is of type 'glong ** {aka long int **}'
 gunichar * g_utf8_to_ucs4_fast (const gchar      *str,
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I looked at the transpiled C source code and the third argument to `g_utf8_to_ucs4_fast` is the address of an uninitialized pointer to long which is later freed with `g_free`. This triggers a segfault when the program is run.

Am I doing something wrong in the way I'm calling this function? It's declared as `public string32 to_utf32_fast (long len = -1, out long? items_written = null)`.

I'm new to Vala (more familiar with C) and not sure I grasp the argument annotations. The second argument shouldn't be transpiled to C as `long **` rather than `long *`, but maybe the nullability marker `?` or the default value `= null` leads Vala to think that the variable `items_written` is a pointer to `long` (or the Vala equivalent thereof) rather than `long`. If so, then maybe there is an error in the declaration of the method or an ambiguity in Vala syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration is wrong. This code works just fine:

```
[CCode (cname = "g_utf8_to_ucs4_fast")]
public extern string32 to_utf32_fast_ (string s, long len = -1,
    out long items_written);

int main (string[] args) {
    string test = "abc";
    long codepoint_count;
    string32 utf32_version = to_utf32_fast_(test, -1, out codepoint_count);
    stdout.printf("success");
    return 0;
}
```

In the original declaration from glib-2.0.vapi the items_written parameter would be a `glong**` in C, but it actually is a `glong*`.

I have reported this as a bug:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vala/issues/634

Comment: Thanks! And declaring as `public extern string32 to_utf32_fast_ (string s, long len = -1, out long items_written = null)` allows the third parameter to be omitted.